# Codeigniter : Problem inserting accents in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, internationalization

I'm trying out code igniter, and I came across an error message while trying to insert a new row in my Mysql database.

The text I'm trying to insert is in French, and contains some accents.

Here's my code :

```
    $data= array(
        'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
        'date' => $this->input->post('date'),
        'mytext' => $this->input->post('mytext')
        );
    
    $this->db->insert('blog', $data);
```

This code seems to work fine (I've inserted a few "test test" entries), but when I try to enter something with accents, for instance "*Il était là*", I get an error message :

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1366
>
> Incorrect string value: '\xE9tait ...' for column 'mytext' at row 1

I've looked on the code igniter forums for a fix, but all they say is to change the collation to UTF8, in mysql. I've tried that, but I keep having the same problem.

Comment: utf8_encode() works, thanks !

It's weird, I've never had to use that function on my previous project, which I am re-doing using code igniter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to uft8-encode it before you insert to the database.

```
utf8_encode($string)
```